# partial derivative of garch model

Tags: statistics

In this [PDF](http://www.ams.sunysb.edu/~yiyang/research/computational_finance/Parameter_Estimation_of_GARCH_Model.pdf), page 3. When computing $\frac{\partial l_t(\theta)}{\partial\theta}$. It appears that $\frac{\partial \epsilon_t^2(\theta)}{\partial\theta}=0$. Can someone explain to me why this is true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems $\epsilon_t$ is not to a function of $\theta$. If that is so, its derivative wrt $\theta$ is zero.